# How to set size of object on form in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have panel and Datagridview on Form, panel is for sliding up and down to show and hide its contents.

[image]

When I click on show button it executes this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (hidded)
    {
        button1.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Visible = true;
        button2.Visible = false;
    }
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (hidded)
    {                
        Spanel.Height = Spanel.Height + 20;
        Datagridview1.Location = new Point(23 , Datagridview1.Location.Y + 20);
        if (Spanel.Height >= 140)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            hidded = false;
            this.Refresh();
        }
   }
   else
   {
       Spanel.Height = Spanel.Height - 20;
       Datagridview1.Location = new Point( 23, Datagridview1.Location.Y - 20);

       if (Spanel.Height <= 0)
       {
           timer1.Stop();
           hidded = true;
           this.Refresh();
       }
   }
```

}

when i try to hide/close  panel the Datagridview moves up and become like this:

[image]

I just need to fix anchor size or datagridview location from down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it your way (with timer) just change your timer tick event handler to the code bellow. It will also change the size of the DataGridView alongside with its position.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (hidded)
    {
        Spanel.Height = Spanel.Height + 20;
        Datagridview1.Location = new Point(23, Datagridview1.Location.Y + 20);
        Datagridview1.Size = new Size(Datagridview1.Width, Datagridview1.Height - 20);
        if (Spanel.Height >= 140)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            hidded = false;
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Spanel.Height = Spanel.Height - 20;
        Datagridview1.Location = new Point(23, Datagridview1.Location.Y - 20);
        Datagridview1.Size = new Size(Datagridview1.Width, Datagridview1.Height + 20);
        if (Spanel.Height <= 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            hidded = true;
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

My approach to this problem would be a bit different and if u don't mind i will let it here. Instead of anchoring i would do it like this(see the pic bellow) using docking. It should work the same using the code you posted (Your SPanel is Panel2 on the picture).
[image: Your form layout]
Edit #1: For fluently moving or resizing controls in your WinForm app i recommend you to use this library: https://github.com/UweKeim/dot-net-transitions. Using the mentioned library your button click event hanlder would look something like this:

```
private bool resizing = false;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (resizing) 
        return;

    resizing = true;
    Transition t = new Transition(new TransitionType_Acceleration(600));
    t.TransitionCompletedEvent += (snd, ea) => { resizing = false; };
    t.add(panel2, "Height", panel2.Height == 0 ? 250 : 0);
    t.run();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help
these two lines make it works brother :
    `    Datagridview1.Location = new Point(23, Datagridview1.Location.Y + 20);
        Datagridview1.Size = new Size(Datagridview1.Width, Datagridview1.Height - 20);
`
so please change your answer to them to choose it as correct Answer.

Comment: I changed the order of the solutions, but if u don't mind i also kept the 2nd one and labeled it as 'My approach'.

Comment: I agree with @eren you can do a lot with that code. You can use it to give slide effects and other things. Also, if you need a visual tutorial I did this as a tutorial lesson on my YouTube channel a few weeks ago.